# flutter pop back to navigated route

Tags: flutter, dart

i am looking for proper solution to pop back to page where user was navigated. I already found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64882217/4862911) answer but i do believe there should be more proper way to do that. Any idea except the link that i shared?

Comment: Hey @aligur what's your code to navigate to the page initially?

Comment: Add some more information about your issue like : some code or some images related to what you want to achieve

Comment: @AnkitKumarMaurya
actually I was just trying to navigate back user to page which is redirected to user actual page.

for example  A --> B -->C then when I click any button inside C page then the user must be redirected the A which was started the navigation. but the A page might be D, E, X etc. For example if the navigation like X --> B --> C then the user must be redirected to X instead of page A

Comment: @Percent.twof can u please take a look recent comment that I posted

Comment: @aligur hey man, I'm sorry I didn't see your comment! Please see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pop until a certain page by doing `Navigator.popUntil()`

For example:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.settings.name == "MyWidget");
```

Just change "My Widget" to the name of the class you need to go back to and you'll be all good! Alternatively, you can try:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
```

---

Edit after @aligur's comment:

@aligur you could do the following, though it's not great form:

Setup a "globals" dart file, and put a variable in it. For example:

```
String pageToGoBackTo = "";
```

And whenever you know what page you want to set as the one to go back to, you set this variable to that page's route name. Then when you want to go back to it you can do:

```
Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.settings.name == pageToGoBackTo);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Good luck! :)

Comment: it works but the main point, as I mentioned on the answer, 'MyWidget' will be the dynamic. and I don't want to pass where I came from as parameter to constructor method. I think its overkill. is there any spesific solution for that?

Comment: @aligur updated answer xx